# Mac Automator "get web page content"

Tags: macos, automator, webarchive

I'm trying to create a workflow in Automator to save as webarchive the web page content of an already opened web page in safari. What I did is

1. get the url from the only one web page opened in safari
2. use the command "get web page content"

The workflow works well (just because is very simple :-D ) and "create" in results the webarchive file. But, at this point, I cannot manage the file created. I need to save this web archive and rename it as a txt file. I don't know how to move, copy or save the webarchive file.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advantage". That doesn't even make _sense_.